When is a $k$-dimensional regular smooth surface $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the intersection of $n-k$ hypersurfaces of the form $f_i(x_1,...,x_n)=0$?
The $f_i$ mentioned above are (linearly independent and) smooth. I want to find a necessary and sufficient condition for it. Some progress on it is as follows. If $M=\bigcap f^{-1}_i(0)$，grad$f_i$ are sections of the normal bundle over $M$, moreover if grad$f_i$ are linearly independent in $T\mathbb{R}^n$, they span a $(n-k)$-distribution $D$ in $T\mathbb{R}^n$. From Frobenius theorem, the distribution $D$ is integrable iff $\Gamma(D)$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. But I can't find any precise condition for the question.
So are there already some results about it?

Maybe you want the Implicit Function Theorem?

@AndrewD.Hwang  Could you explain why it is useful for my question ?

Here is a possibly more friendly account. If I understand, you have $k$ functions of $n$ variables whose gradients are linearly independent at each point of their common zero set. The point is, the implicit function theorem guarantees the zero set is locally the graph of a smooth mapping of $(n-k)$ variables (taking values in $\mathbf{R}^{k}$), hence a manifold. If I understand your assumptions, Frobenius is unnecessary here.
